# Fetch all entities in collection except entities that match a specific condition

Tags: jpa, jpql

I would like to select an entity, and also eagerly fetch a property that contains a collection of other entities. Except i only want to fetch the elements in the collection that match a specific condition. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT u FROM User u
LEFT JOIN FETCH u.documents d
WHERE u.id = :userId
AND d.type = 'PASSPORT' <--- Only fetch documents that are of type 'PASSPORT'
```

To be clear, the above query doesn't do what i want, it just 'filters' the User entity to users that have a PASSPORT.

My desired outcome: If my User has 3 documents, respectively of type 'PASSPORT', 'ID' and 'CONTRACT', i ONLY want to fetch the User and the PASSPORT, and nothing else. If my user has no PASSPORT, i want to fetch only the User, and no documents.

Comment: What is the current behavior of your query and how is it wrong?

Comment: The current query only fetches Users that have a 'PASSPORT' document

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the restriction on the password type to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT u
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN u.documents d
    ON d.type = 'PASSPORT'
WHERE u.id = :userId
```

This change will prevent any entity/record from being filtered off solely on the passport type.  Instead, users which do not match the passport type should still appear in the resulting collection.

Comment: I think this is close, although i'm getting an exception: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters`. Is this a hibernate-specific problem?

Comment: @P.Protas Try removing `FETCH` and see if that would run without error.

Comment: Well the documents table is FetchType.LAZY, so removing FETCH will cause errors in the code that requires u.documents (no session). I can't change the FetchType to EAGER, that would mess up too much logic in our legacy codebase

Comment: Then you might have to go with `use filters` ... I have gotten the above query to work in the past IIRC.

Comment: I tried using filters using [this guide](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-filter/), unfortunately filters don't work in this case either, since the Document entity is an association on my User entity, and there is no join table. So the solution the article provides that used @FilterJoinTable is not relevant in my case. I ended up just filtering the documents in Java code using `.removeIf(d -> d.getType() != DocumentType.PASSPORT)`